# CPU- and memory-usage histogram for performance of a java program

Tags: java, performance, memory, histogram, cpu-usage

I have 3 different projects in eclipse, that solve the same problem but use different approaches. I want to know which of these projects is the best in terms of cpu- and memory-usage. I need a histogram for each project (I run them one after another) that shows the memory- and cpu-usage in a histogram. I tried [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) but it only shows the actual memory/cpu usage and you cant have a whole graph and save it.
I also came across the [Eclipse Test & Performance Tools Platform Project](https://eclipse.org/tptp/) but it seems to be discontinued.

I would be thankful for a program to create such a graph or atleast some java-code to provide me with a timestamp and a memory/cpu-usage rate. But the former one would be better of course

Comment: Selphiron - Did you ever figure out the best approach for you?  I need to do something similar.  I need to collect performance metrics for my application and display them graphically for customer consumption.  I too tried VisualVM but I have 4 separate processes running at the same time all talking to each other as one application.

Comment: Hi! I used the windows tool perfmon.exe to gather data and visualized them with [plotly](http://plot.ly) . It is quite a bit of work but the results are very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try looking at Java Flight Recorder (JFR). It is now included as part of Java 7 & 8.
You can profile your application using JFR and later analyze using Java Mission Control.
It provides a comprehensive view of what is going on inside the VM.